# how to remove Some NA with respect of 2 groups

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have

```
    HH    PP    mode
    1      1     2
    1      1     NA
    1      1     NA
    1      2     2
    1      2     2
    1      3     NA
    1      3    NA
    2      1     2
    2      1     NA
    2      2     NA
    2      2     NA
```

first column is household index and second is persons in each household. I want to remove rows whose are NA in mode for each person in each household.for example in the first household mode column for third person is all NA so I want to remove it. same for second person in second family

output:

```
    HH    PP    mode
    1      1     2
    1      1     NA
    1      1     NA
    1      2     2
    1      2     2
    2      1     2
    2      1     NA
```

Comment: Did you try anything? This is also a duplicate...

Comment: I was trying to do df %>% group_by(HH,PP) %>% filter(is.na(mode)) but it does not give what I want. how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dt[, .SD[ ( !all( is.na( mode ) ) ) ], by= .( HH, PP ) ][]

   HH PP mode
1:  1  1    2
2:  1  1   NA
3:  1  1   NA
4:  1  2    2
5:  1  2    2
6:  2  1    2
7:  2  1   NA
```

**sample data**

```
dt <- fread("    HH    PP    mode
    1      1     2
    1      1     NA
    1      1     NA
    1      2     2
    1      2     2
    1      3     NA
    1      3    NA
    2      1     2
    2      1     NA
    2      2     NA
    2      2     NA")
```

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(WithDriving, , .SD[(!all(is.na(mode.car)))], by = .(SAMPN,  : 
  unused argument (by = .(SAMPN, PERNO))

Comment: dt has to be of class `data.table`.. see sample data.

Comment: I used as.data.table for my data

Comment: can't say.. it is working on the sample data provided... try that first